# How to automatically reject emails from email addresses?

Tags: spam-prevention, yahoo-mail

In my Yahoo! account I get a lot of spam emails. They are automatically moved in Spam folder.

But it's very annoying to delete the spam emails, so that's why I want to automatically reject such emails.

I imagine the following scenario:

1. I get a spam email comming from `something@example.com` that already is in *Spam* folder.
2. I review it and I decide to block any emails from `something@example.com`
3. Next time when new emails come from that email addresses are automatically blocked.

How can I do this?